# IntelliJ Diff tool not showing differences (Android Studio)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, diff

The differences tool in Android Studio (v1.5) has stopped showing differences.  Project is versioned with git.  Any file I check reports 'no differences' in the top right, when differences can visually be seen between the two files shown in default viewer.  No line by line differences are shown.  Now, if the view is changed from 'default viewer' to 'oneside viewer,' then the differences are shown in the differences tool.  So the problem appears to be with the default viewer.

I've invalidated cache and restarted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to change **Highlight**.

> Make **Do not Highlight** --> **Highlight split changes**

That is worked in my IDE.